# Simple php echo issue in html

Tags: php

I'm playing around with creating iphone webpages with html5 and using php, in my code below when I run it for some reason the php part instead of echoing the variable it doesn't print anything to the screen, any ideas?  thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iphone.css" media="screen"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>


      <h1></h1>
      <h2></h2>
      <ul>
        <li class="arrow"><center><a href="">Out</a></center>
        <li class="arrow"><center><a href="">Connect</a></center>
        <li class="arrow"><center><a href="">Disconnect</a></center>



      </ul>
      <center><p>Status:</p>
      <?php
$myString = "Hello!";
echo $myString;
?>
      </center>

    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5. Use CSS for presentation.

Comment: Are you sure php is ran? Check the generated source.

Comment: View the source in your browser and see if its there.

Answer (score 3):

Have you saved the file as a .php file? Is your Apache module running correctly? Is PHP running correctly? I can't think of anything else that could be wrong, your code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Variable names [are case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). You need to change your code to reflect this.</del> (My bad, looks like that was correct in your original post.

<del>Also,</del> Is this all saved into a .php file? If not, then you need to rename your file as such. (Ex: rename `index.html` to `index.php`, and try opening it again on an Apache server)

Comment: Can't you see that proper capitalisation is used above?

Answer (score 1):

1) The `<center></center>` tag has been deprecated. Try using the `text-align:center` css property.

2) What extension did you name the file? What server are you running (if any) the PHP interpreter on? Make sure you have a properly configured server, and name your file with a `.php` extension.

3) To test to see if your server is actually parsing and executing PHP, put this file in the doc root of your server and see if anything renders

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```